# Are there at least $3$ groups of order $16$ that has element of order $8$?

Tags: group-theory

Are there at least $3$ groups of order $16$ that has element of order $8$?

I know that probably the simplest way of doing this problem is looking at the element structure of the abelian groups of order $16$, but I want to know if there is another way of doing this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Well the cyclic group $C_{16}$, the dihedral group $D_{18}$ and the direct product $C_8\times C_2$ are already three examples.

Comment: I believe you meant $D_{16}$.  Thanks for the answer. I wasn't very clear in my question,  but I wanted another method for solving other than looking at the already known groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; we can say more: there are at least three **non-abelian** groups of order $16$ with an element of order  $8$.

We can say something more again - there are **exactly four** non-abelian groups of order $16$ with an element of order $8$.

To see *best* possible result, see [this page](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=iebSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&dq=p-groups%20having%20cyclic%20maximal%20subgroup&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6zuaj2cfNAhUHt48KHagYDacQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=p-groups%20having%20cyclic%20maximal%20subgroup&f=false) (The Theory of Finite Groups, Hans Kurzweil, Bernd Stellmacher, p.108)

Comment: This is a standard theorem in $p$-groups, and many books of group theory give its proof, without putting it as an exercise. In other words, the proof of this fact is available in many books. Hence, instead of posting complete answer, I provided a link for it.

Comment: but page 108 is unable for view *edit: now I did see it. thanks

Comment: now see, it is visible? Otherwise, you may search "p-groups with cyclic maximal subgroup" in "Google books", some common texts will give you more links.